# Non -Ram Storage

Tags: java, storage, ram

I am learning java from **"Thinking In Java"** by *Bruce Eckel*. I am unable to understand the concept of Non -Ram Storage.

As the book says:

> *Non-RAM storage*. If data lives completely outside a program, it can
>   exist while the program is not running, outside the control of the
>   program. The two primary examples of this are streamed objects, in
>   which objects are turned into streams of bytes, generally to be sent
>   to another machine, and persistent objects, in which the objects are
>   placed on disk so they will hold their state even when the program is
>   terminated. The trick with these types of storage is turning the
>   objects into something that can exist on the other medium, and yet can
>   be resurrected into a regular RAM-based object when necessary. Java
>   provides support for lightweight persistence,and mechanism such as
>   JDBC!

What is lightweight persistence?..what is meant by turning the objects into something that can exist on the other medium, and yet can be resurrected into a regular RAM-based object when necessary?

Comment: Stop! Using! So! Much! Exclamation! Marks!

Comment: Sorry i removed them.

Comment: data files and databases

Comment: THis is no different than storage in C.  You have some structure in your running process that has data members.  You may need a way to save the structure's contents to disk for later re-load.  Same concept in Java, but there are some built-in behaviors (serialization) that make it simpler.  JDBC is a framework for saving data to a database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Persistent data is information that can outlive the program that creates it. The majority of complex programs use persistent data: GUI applications need to store user preferences across program invocations, web applications track user movements and orders over long periods of time, etc. (source provided below)

Here is the answer your question:
Lightweight persistence is a storage area which requires a little or no work from the developer side. Examples:Java serialization is a form of lightweight persistence because it can be used to persist Java objects directly to a file with very little effort.

I am very happy that you are not just reading the book...rather you are asking questions about anything you come across in the book. good luck

[source](http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/1.2.3/apache-openjpa/docs/jpa_overview_intro_transpers.html)

Answer (score 2):

There is a processing in java (and other languages) called serialization.  Basically it lets you turn an object into a byte stream, so it can be written to a file, stored in a database, sent to a cloud, etc.  The idea is that there is an easy and automatic translation between the stored object and the in-memory RAM object.  If you do it yourself, such as writing individual fields to a file or database, you need to come up with a file format or database schema.  This is heavy-weight storage.

Here is a tutorial on java serialization: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_serialization.htm